# convert output of jq from list of lists to delimited string

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, jq

I have a json file which I'm outputing two numbers (lat/lon) and the output now is

```
[
  2.294891,
  48.875284
]
[
  -2.14908,
  53.281214
]
[
  1.963667,
  48.768891
]
[
  -3.739434,
  40.390413
]
```

what I want is the numbers to become strings and be concatenated like

```
2.294891,48.875284
-2.14908,53.281214
...
```

but I don't know how to do it with jq.

**Update:**

I could convert the output to

```
[2.294891,48.875284]
[-2.14908,53.281214]
[1.963667,48.768891]
```

with -c argument and use tr -d [ | tr -d ] in the pipe to remove the brackets but I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy!

```
$ jq -r @csv input.json 
2.294891,48.875284
-2.14908,53.281214
1.963667,48.768891
-3.739434,40.390413
```

Beware, though, that the precision may differ (or in general, be lost).